# "<Python.h> no such file or directory"

Tags: python, c, ubuntu

I am trying to use the <Python.h> header file but I cannot get it to be found. I am using ubuntu 20.04. I have seen many similar questions on stack overflow but none solve my problem. I have tried doing:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.9-dev
```

but this does not resolve my problem. I can also do Windows but #include <Python.h> produced the same error on Windows and I couldn't resolve it there so I moved to ubuntu. I am using Python3.9. Please can I have some suggestions as to what could be the problem?

Comment: Do `dpkg-query -L python3.9-dev`.  That should show you where it installed the header file.  Make sure that path is in the -I flag passed to the compiler.

Comment: Sounds like a question for https://askubuntu.com/ .

Comment: @Steffo Not really. Setting up your build process to locate external headers is not only an issue for Ubuntu. (As evidenced by the fact that the OP also had the issue in Windows.)

Comment: But note that `Python.h` is not provided by `python3.9-dev`.  You want to look in `libpython3.9-dev`

Comment: @WilliamPursell, when I try that command I get:
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python3.9
/usr/share/doc/python3.9/HISTORY.gz
/usr/share/doc/python3.9/README.maintainers
/usr/share/doc/python3.9/README.valgrind.gz
/usr/share/doc/python3.9/gdbinit.gz
/usr/share/doc/python3.9/pybench.log
/usr/share/doc/python3.9/test_results.gz
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/bin/python3.9-config
/usr/share/doc/python3.9-dev
/usr/share/man/man1/python3.9-config.1.gz
And it doesn't seem clear to me where Python.h is from this

Comment: @AmeenIzhac You need to query libpython3.9-dev instead of python3.9-dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what the context is, but you may just need to do:

```
sudo apt-get install libpython3.9-dev
```

If that doesn't work, do something like:

```
CPPFLAGS="${CPPFLAGS} -I $(dirname $(dpkg -L libpython3.9-dev | grep Python.h))"
```

And make sure you compile with the appropriate flags.  That is, if you are building with `gcc`, use:

`gcc $CPPFLAGS ...`

Comment: I have done this: sudo apt-get install libpython3.9-dev
but it didn't solve my problem

For the below suggestion, I don't really understand what that flag means but do you meant I should run:

gcc ${CPPFLAGS} -I $(dirname $(dpkg -L libpython3.9-dev | grep Python.h)) pythonToC.c -o pythonToC
?

Comment: No, the second suggestion is just showing a way to set CPPFLAGS, with the expectation that you are calling `gcc ${CPPFLAGS}` (or your build system is adding CPPFLAGS).  If you're building by hand, just do `gcc -I /path/to/dir` where /path/to/dir is determined by `dpkg -L`

Answer (score 2):

1. Find the the directory where `Python.h` lives.
2. Add `-Ipath` to your gcc command line. `path`is the directory found in point 1.
3. Enjoy

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the directory